# How does this Op Amp affect voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a circuit as follows:

[image]

Note that \$V^+\$ is a voltage source that has both an AC and DC component. I want to see how the OpAmp affects both components. My guess is that we can write:

$$V_{out}(AC)=(1 + \frac{R2}{R1} - \frac{X_c}{\sqrt{X_c^2+ R_1^2}})V^+(AC) $$

Where I assumed the role of the RC part as a low pass filter as seen by \$V^+\$. Then, since low pass filters let all DC pass through unaffected, I would say that as long as C1 is not very large, $$V_{out}(DC)=(1 + \frac{R2}{R1})V^+(DC) $$

If I was told C1 is large enough to be considered as a short for AC and an open for DC, I would say $$V_{out}(AC)=(1 + \frac{R2}{R1})V^+(AC)$$ and $$V_{out}(DC)=V^+(DC)$$

Can someone tell me if this is correct or provide alternative explanations?

Comment: Is R3 present for some reason?

Comment: Nope, it was just a nice picture I found that included R3, but it does not affect the OpAmp.

Comment: @Andyaka: Do you understand why you might want to balance the input bias currents?

Comment: @DaveTweed I don’t think you need to ask that of me. I was concerned about the dot on the schematic and whether the opamp was a voltage feedback type, hence the pertinent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagram explains everything

[image]

At DC the capacitor reactance is very high (open circuit)\$X_C = \infty \$.

So, op-amp work as a voltage follower (gain one).

As the input signal frequency increases the capacitor reactance decreases.

And when \$X_C = (R_1 + R_2) \$ at \$F_1 = \frac{1}{2 \pi C_1 (R_1 + R2)}\$

The op-amp voltage gain start to increases and will reach \$ \large (1 +\frac{R_2}{R_1})\$ for signal frequency larger than :

\$\large F_2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi C_1 R_1}\$ When \$X_C < R_1\$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the basic concept right. The other interesting question is, what is the frequency at which the transition between the two regimes occurs?

---

Actually, your first equation isn't quite right. It should be

$$V_{out} = V_{in} (1 + \frac{Z2}{Z1})$$

where Z2 = R2, and Z1 = the series combination of R1and C1.

It becomes

$$V_{out} = V_{in} (1 + \frac{R2}{R1 - \frac{1}{j\omega C1}})$$

This reduces to your other equations in the limit cases.

Comment: Well, I would probably say it is the cutoff frequency or something related to it?

Comment: Yes, but how do you determine its value from the component values?

Comment: Also, I was wondering, I see how I get \$V_{out}(AC)\$ by taking the limit of \$X_c \to 0\$, however, I cannot see how taking this limit changes the DC gain from \$ 1 + \frac{R2}{R1}\$ to 1.

Comment: I would compute \$f_c = \frac1{2\pi R_1C_1}\$

Comment: It doesn't. You get the DC gain by taking the limit \$X_c \rightarrow \infty\$.

Comment: The equation you just corrected refers to my second equation, right? I thought the first one was okay.

Comment: No, the first one is wrong.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your help. Could you please clarify one more question? Will the capacitor C1 act as an open circuit for all DC signals, regardless of the actual value of C1?

Comment: Well, yes. The characteristics of a capacitor do not depend on the signal. But if your "DC signal" is varying at all, then there's an AC component, and then the effect of the capacitor does depend on its size.