# Finding the transfer function of an non-inverting audio op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, control-system

I am just doing some independent re-search for myself in audio amplifier (CHIP AMPS) such as the LM1875.

I want to learn more about how to compensate for audio chip amps and how their bode plot works and bandwidths, but in order to indulge on this I need to do some math to prove it to myself.

[image]

This is the LM1875 that I designed. Simply I want to just understand why C2 is used for as I have heard it's there to make your DC gain (22.2dB) flat among many frequencies which is true as shown here:

[image]

My idea was to make a transfer function of this op amp (Very simplify shown below) and just do a frequency analysis where s->jw and sweep it on the bode plot.

Here is my attempt:

Assuming this model now: [image]

Node VA = The voltage between the cap and the resistor.

First Node:

\$ \frac{V_{IN}-V_{OUT}}{R_{6}} + \frac{V_{A}-V_{IN}}{R_{7}} = 0\$

\$ V_{IN}(s)*[\frac{R_{7}}{R_{6}}+1]-\frac{V_{OUT}(s)*R_{7}}{R_{6}}= V_{A}(s) (1)\$

Second Node:

\$ \frac{V_{A}-V_{IN}}{R7} + C_{2}* \dot V_{A} = 0\$

\$ VA(s)*[1+R_{7}*sC_{2}] = V_{IN}(s) \$

\$ VA(s) = \frac{V_{IN}(s)}{1+R_{7}*sC_{2}} \$

Sub (2) into (1)

\$ V_{IN}(s)*[\frac{R_{7}}{R_{6}}+1]-\frac{V_{OUT}(s)*R_{7}}{R_{6}}= \frac{V_{IN}(s)}{1+R_{7}*sC_{2}} \$

Which comes down to:

\$ H(s)=\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}= \frac{6.11s+1}{0.470s+1}\$

Bode plot:

[image]

Comment: The TF is \$\large \frac{V_{out}}{V_{G1}}=\frac{1+C_2(R_6+R_7)s}{1+R_7C_2s}\$. But you need a balanced power supply, or lift the input signal above ground.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean balanced power supply or lifting the input signal

The transfer function is the same as mine?

Comment: You've got a negative sign in the TF. The output can't go more negative than the negative supply rail. If the input goes negative ...

Comment: Oh yes? I have an input circuitry that compensates for this? Using the voltage divider to bias the input voltage half of the supply, so it does go "negative" which is 0. The mapping is essentially 48 - 24 - 0 oppose to 24 0 -24

Comment: OK, tidy up your diagram, then.

Comment: Please look at diagram 1 more carefully then, you can see the voltage divider network there as R3 and R4.

Comment: Your gain plot says it all. The impedance of the cap becomes very high at low frequencies, so the gain of the amp becomes very low. This produces low DC offsets during operation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thank you, just nice to know I am on the right track.

yeah sorry about the confusion
1. Was to confirm my transfer function was correct.

2. How do I further compensate the op amp, how do I know when to add zero/poles etc to the system. Essentially how do I compensate the op amp in general.

Comment: Also how to control the lower and higher frequencies of the op amp bandwidth.

Comment: The title says inverting, but all the circuits you show are non-inverting.

Comment: I made a mistake sorry about that, I am taking about inverting amplifier

Comment: What the bleep is with your bode plot frequency axis? Those increments are truly bizarre. Such a thing is only legible in octaves or decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, your circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Oc9H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see your audio amplifier is supplied from a single power supply.

This is why you need a DC bias network. Because every "active device" to work properly as an amplifier supplied from a single source need proper bias circuit. When you use BJT as a CE amplifier, you use a voltage divider to bias the active device somewhere in the "linear region".

In case of single supply op-amp, you have to do the same thing. 
We need to bias the op-amp somewhere in the middle of his "linear region".

And this is a job for \$R_4,R_3\$ voltage divider. And this voltage divider "set" the DC bias at \$0.5 V_{CC}\$. 
We can say that this circuit sets the "virtual ground" for our opamp.

\$R_2\$ and \$C_7\$ were added to the circuit to improve the power supply noise rejection. Without it (\$R2 = 0\Omega\$) any "noise" present at supply rail will appear at the amplifier noninverting input and will be amplified by the amp thirteen times (\$1 + \frac{R_6}{R_7}\$).

In the same time \$R_2\$ resistor sets the input impedance of the amplifier seen by the input AC signal source.

Because the power opamp can also amplify any DC voltage present at the noninverting input the \$C_2\$ capacitor was added to address this issue. 
Without the \$C_2\$ capacitor, the output DC voltage will be equal to Vcc (0.5Vcc * 1+R6/R7). But we have this capacitor in the circuit, so DC voltage gain is reduced to one. And the output voltage is equal to \$0.5 V_{CC}\$.

Across opamp, we see a typical negative feedback network for a noninverting amplifier. 
Read this:
[How does this Op Amp affect voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374867/how-does-this-op-amp-affect-voltage/374882#374882)

Additional \$C_4\$ was added to reduce AC gain at high frequency (above F > Xc4 = R5 ). \$F = \frac{0.16}{50pF * 12k\Omega} = 267kHz \$

The input network also looks typical for an AC coupling audio amplifier.

\$R_1\$ is a pull-down resistor when no input signal is connected.

\$R_2\$ and \$C_3\$ form an input low-pass filter (260kHz) to protect the amplifier from unwanted high frequency (RF) signals at the amplifier input.

\$C_{11}\$ is an input AC coupling capacitor and together with \$R2\$ forms a high-pass filter and set required low-frequency cutoff.

The output networks also look ordinary. And they are here to prevent high-frequency oscillations.

\$R_9\$ and \$C_5\$ form what is called a Zobel network.
The purpose of the Zobel network is to ensure that opamp output
stage sees some "real"(resistive) load at very high frequencies.

Series L-R network (\$L_1,R_{10}\$) was also added to help ensure the amplifier will not oscillate at HF. 
At high frequencies, the impedance of the inductor (\$X_L\$) increases and isolates the opamp output from unwanted capacitive loads. 
And the \$R_{10}\$ resistor was added to damp the resonances that the inductor might have in combination with load capacitance at HF.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78320/discussion-on-answer-by-g36-finding-transfer-function-of-an-inverting-audio-op-a).

Answer (score 1):

You are starting from a bit of a strange place. It is standard practice to run op amps from split supply rails (in audio typically +/-15 to +/-18V), and reference everything to the 0V which is obviously half way between the two.

It is possible of course to run these circuits from a single supply (for instance a 9V battery) but then there is always some kind of "hack" to create a mid-rail reference (which would be at 4.5V in this case). These workarounds are fine and work quite well (there are even [special IC's](http://www.ti.com/product/TLE2426) for the purpose) but this is not the place to learn op amp fundamentals, because it does confuse the issue.

Regarding C2 in your circuit - it is not there to make "DC gain flat" as you say - quite the opposite. In audio, we typically do *not* want a flat frequency response to DC (or, the other way, up into the MHz region). There are good reasons to limit the bandwidth (keeping out RFI, pops and plosives from microphones, and so on) and well-designed systems have at least one -3dB point at either end - one typically at 10-20Hz, and another somewhere between 20kHz and say 100kHz or so (perhaps higher if marketing to people who believe in magic is a big concern).

Anyway, audiophile arguments aside, if we take a simple, standard non-inverting amplifier, without all the surrounding components and with no capacitors to control bandwidth (and no supplies shown, but remember that supplies of say +/-15V are there, and 0V is therefore in the middle of the working range):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1qkD3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has several important characteristics:
1. the input impedance is extremely high (many megOhms)
2. it is non-inverting.
3. the gain is given by (1 + R2/R1) (and therefore always > 1).
4. for the argument, let's say that this is an *ideal* opamp - so now we have "DC to light" frequency response. The gain part of the Bode plot is a straight line.

If we now place a capacitor in series with R1, we now that the the effective impedance from the + input to ground will now rise with frequency. If gain is high (R2 >> R1), the gain approximates R2/R1, and at the frequency where Xc = R1 we will be more or less 3dB down on the in-band. (A few minutes with a calculator will show that this is always an electrolytic with typically several 100uF value.)

By the same token, putting a cap across R2 increases the negative feedback with frequency, and hence reduces gain. Therefore, this is one of the standard methods for setting the upper -3dB point. (This cap usually ends up in the 100's of pF range, a ceramic or film type is usual.)

(In fact, I did a bit of hand-waving here to simplify the maths by assuming high gain which is not always the case. But it is quite often the case that the bandwidth limiting is done in a high-gain stage, as it also helps ensure stability. And given the poor accuracy of the caps used to do this, there is not that much point to be overly rigorous with the math.)

Comment: Sorry what I meant about DC gain flat is that at low frequencies (0Hz) it doesn't amplify dc

Comment: then you mean DC gain is minus infinity. The amp blocks DC, and has no gain at all (there will be some very small gain at say 1Hz). Terminology is important. "Flat" in this context means a response that does *not* vary with frequency.

Comment: I mean yea sorry about that, all I know due to the NFB at low frequencies any dc will be * 1 thus the same at the output

Comment: sorry, my bad. Indeed, gain is unity at DC for this circuit.

Comment: Yeah exactly.

Another question though do you know anything about how create the bandwidth of the op amp shown in figure 2 and creating  zobel network?

Comment: well, the scales of fig 2 are so coarse that it is hard to see, but it seems that there are -3dB points somewhere around 10Hz and 100k or so. Zobel network is normally found at the output of a power amp, to help stability into a loudspeaker load - generally not something used in small signal design (I have seen it occasionally in things like VCA based circuits). It's just a series CR circuit I think. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Yeah I get the zobel network is found at the output, but how does one design its C and R values. I am trying to build an amplifier chip amp from scratch using the LM1875.

Comment: well, the device datasheet recommends 1R and 0.22uF so I would go with that. Quite likely it is not that critical but usually the people that write the datasheets are on point.

Comment: I see I see, how about the Thiele network? Anyways can you explain to me functionality of R1, I thought it was the voltage divider of the source?

Comment: R1 sets the input resistance at DC. Without it the input pin has no connection to GND at DC. I don't know why you would change the output circuit of this chip from the one that TI recommend - there is no reason to do that unless you run into some kind of issue. Start by keeping it simple.

Comment: if you want to learn basics of audio design with opamps, I suggest you get a dual power supply and play around with opamps on the bench. Although a lot of maths is found in text books, in practice you don't use it that much. This is a power amp chip, and there's no reason why you shouldn't build it and have fun with it, but these things are typically implemented according to the datasheet. Standard opamp circuits though are worth understanding, and actually building them and seeing what they do will get you much further than lots of math. Hope you don't mind the word of advice.

Comment: Of course not, appreciate the time you spent on this. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. One further thought about Zobel network - why it is hard to arrive at values by calculation : its purpose is to improve stability into a very inductive load (which also varies a lot with frequency). I suppose the bit of capacitance helps correct that a bit. But as we don't know what speaker the actual load will be (and they vary so much anyway) exact calculation is probably not going to happen. Typical values I have seen are 1-10R, 2-10nF. I suspect that it is not that critical within that range. Interesting question.