# Filter question, shelf or pass?

Tags: amplifier, operational-amplifier

In the circuit below:

[image]

I often see capacitors like C4 added in the feedback path of a non-inverting audio amplifier, and often times I heard that it acts like a high-pass filter.

However...

At low frequencies, C4 is open, and at high frequencies, C4 is a short circuit.

But R1 isn't changed. And there is no "DC blocking capacitor" shown by default. So does placing a capacitor in series with the "low-side feedback resistor" (R2 in the circuit) make the amplifier a **high *pass* filter** or a **high *shelf* filter?**

Comment: I would say high shelf. At low frequencies, the gain is unity, and at high frequencies, the gain is 12.

Comment: Thanks! Everyone keeps saying that it's a "high pass" and I believed it until I saw that there was no blocking capacitor, so yeah, it must be high *shelf,* not high *pass.* You'd need another capacitor and resistor ahead of the amp to do that.

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374867/how-does-this-op-amp-affect-voltage/374882#374882 and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377355/finding-transfer-function-of-an-inverting-audio-op-amp/377431#377431

Comment: When in doubt, try only the equivalent passive filter, sometimes it provides a clearer answer.